# Highstock - Comparison chart doesn't start at 0%

Tags: charts, comparison, highcharts

I'm trying to create a performance chart using the HighStock Comparison graph (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare). The y-axis is a percentage value and the first point on the graph should always start at 0%. The part I'm having trouble with is the graph looks like it always starts at 0% on the second date.

This is the example I'm using. http://jsfiddle.net/hPC4x/
I see two issues 1) The first data point on the graph is outside of the date range for the default 1y range. The range is July 23, 2011 - July 23, 2012 but yet the first data point on the graph starts on July 22, 2011.
2) The start of the graph on July 22, 2011 is a negative value. The graph should start at 0%.

I don't get why an out of date range point would be displayed in the first place. The main issue I'm trying to resolve is getting the graph to start at 0%. I think if I can get the graph to display only within the date range then I might just be able to resolve this issue.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> 1) The first data point on the graph is outside of the date range for
>   the default 1y range. The range is July 23, 2011 - July 23, 2012 but
>   yet the first data point on the graph starts on July 22, 2011

The data outside of the date range is known problem. I don't know whether they have still categorized as bug or not.

I have already posted on this issue on Highstock official forum.

Here is the [link](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=18261) for your reference.

> 2) The start of the graph on July 22, 2011 is a negative value. The
>   graph should start at 0%.

I don't know about that but It should be related to first one.

Comment: Hardik, Thank you for your reply. Your post on Highsoft definitely highlights my 1st issue. I have also made a post on there without seeing your question being posted (http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=19312) I'm going to add your post link to my post as well for reference. I don't know if the first issue will resolve the second issue entirely. Have you found a solution or work around to the first issue or are you still waiting for reply?