# Highstock - Comparison chart should be start with 0%

Tags: highcharts

I am working on highstock and facing  problem that is "y-axis is a percentage value and the first point on the graph should always start at 0%. The part I'm having trouble with is the graph looks like it always starts at 0% on the second date. "

I have found same issue here:
[Highstock - Comparison chart doesn't start at 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640405/highstock-comparison-chart-doesnt-start-at-0)

Following is the details, in case anyone can help me solve the problem.

i am trying to view data between 14th Oct 2008 to 3rd Oct 2012. And the first data point (which should be at 0%, is actually positioned at 9.93%
now when i narrow the window of viewing chart to be between 14th Oct 2008 and 24th June 2010, the first data point is properly positioned to 0%
I find that when i use date range of various intervals, sometimes the 1st data point of graph is correct (i.e positioned at 0%) but sometimes it is positioned at non-zero value.

Why does this happen, I guess my issue is related to the same problem outlined above, but I also tried to track from highcharts issue and the github issue logged. But i could not find any solution as such. Appreciate if anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug which is reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/687

Comment: Yes - i am looking for soluntion..but could not find any comment how to fix it

Comment: It is open bug, and at this moment fix doesn't exist.